# jQuery RangeSlider Widget

Tags: jquery, mobile, rangeslider

I am creating a touch-capable price range-slider using jquery's rangeslider widget seen here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/rangeslider/#entry-examples

(Note: I've found a lot of documentation on using jQuery's slider widget but not rangeslider widget).

Here is working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/E7xYc/1/

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


    <script src="../libraries/js/jquery.mobile.custom/jquery.mobile.custom.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../libraries/js/jquery.mobile.custom/jquery.mobile.custom.structure.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../libraries/js/jquery.mobile.custom/jquery.mobile.custom.theme.css" />

  </head>

  <body>


    <div data-role="rangeslider">
        <input type="range" name="range-1a" id="range-1a" min="0" max="100" value="40">
        <input type="range" name="range-1b" id="range-1b" min="0" max="100" value="80">
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

I've spent hours reading documentation and looking for examples but I can't seem to dynamically set the min,max,and value(s) of the rangeslider.

So.. I moved past dynamically setting values and attempted to bind and onChange event to the rangeSlider and pass the values in a function.  I pull this off, but it's really hacky and I know I'm over complicating this.

Thanks for any help, world.  Ugh.

Comment: @Rooster Hi, Rooster.  By "dynamically set", I mean not hard coding min="0" max="100" value="40" in the HTML.  In other words I want to be able to set these values and update the slider via JS.

Comment: @Rooster I've also failed to get the values of the range-slider when a user changes something.  It's a two-part question.  Sorry for confusion.

Comment: hmm, took a look at the source, and theres not a built in way to set the value via js on init.  You might need to hook into the create function.

Comment: Yuck.  Ok, will keep looking.